# Disable automatic dismissal of iOS alerts on Device Farm

Tags: python, ios, aws-device-farm

It appears alerts on iOS on Device Farm are automatically dismissed can we disable this dismissal as some of my tests are dependent on those alerts. From what I have found from the forums of AWS is that this feature is not yet available but it was few months before.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=716329&#716329

Comment: If you found this answer useful please up vote it so that other users can benefit from it too :)

Answer (score 1):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Today, autoAcceptAlert is set to true by default when using Appium.
However, right now we are looking at ways to give user more control over the options that are passed to Appium. 
You should see an update on this very soon.
This feature wasn't available anytime before.

The AWS forum post will be the best place to get an update on this as soon as it makes it in.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply so for now we are out of luck?

Comment: Until the update is in, unfortunately, pop ups will be auto dismissed.

Comment: If you found this answer useful please up vote it so that other users can benefit from it too :)